# Why do I get the wrong phase shift?

Tags: phase, multisim, phase-shift, phasor

I am trying to compare theory vs simulation values and it seems to be that there are differences. I am using Multisim to simulate a RLC circuit, the LC are in parallel and in series to the resistor.

The circuit is given,
[image]
In the practical I used a function generator with an amplitude of \$10 V_{\text{pp}}\$ (5V to -5V).
Now that I am working on the theory part, I used the maximum value as the magnitude to get the correct voltage, however I keep getting wrong phase shifts.

The parallel components impedance is \$Z=218j\$

Applying the voltage divider rule...
\$V_{R_{1}}=\frac{R_{1}}{Z_{1}+R_{1}}V_{in}\$

\$V_{R_{1}} = (0.75\angle-41^{\circ})(5\angle0)= 3.76\angle-41^{\circ} \text{V}\$

The oscilloscope show's a different angle,

[image]
This shows that VR1 lags Vin.

\$\theta = (2.66\cdot10^{-3}\cdot50\cdot360^{\circ}) = 48^{\circ}\$

When is the magnitude of input voltage phasor 10Vpp and when is it just the maximum 5Vp? Why am I getting big difference in phase shifts (48 compared to -41)? Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: Have you considered that your inductor might not be that accurate; it could be maybe 20% different to what is marked on the component. You clearly are not using the precise peak tops of the waveforms. More care needed is my impression.

Comment: The inductor will also probably have significant series resistance; 650 mH is quite a lot. That will throw things off as well (though not by too much). I recommend also using the zero crossings instead of the peaks, if you must use the cursors manually instead of a measurement function, as those are less difficult to line up your cursors on.

Comment: When the green wave is too late versus red, phase is not "negative"?

Answer (score 1):

> The oscilloscope show's a different angle,

Check this Maple sheet and picture.

When the sine is "too late" versus the generator, the phase is negative.
Is it?

[image]

As pointed out by @Hearth

With your data, the serial resistance of the inductor should be ~ 117 Ohm.
Calculate 20*log10(3.753/4.960)= -4.88 db.
Do AC analysis (parameter rr, serial resistor).  At 50 Hz, just read this value and rr.

[image]

If you make a larger analysis, you should have this (guess: min @ 200 Hz).

[image]